# TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate local similarities using case base reasoning algorithm.
However, I encounter this type error where is in series.py?
Can someone pls tell me what does it mean? How to solve this problem?

```
#loop
for i in range(pCase_base.shape[0]):
    for j in range(pCase_base.shape[1]):
        local_similarity[i,j]=1-(abs(pCases.iloc[:,j]-pCase_base.iloc[i,j])/range_value.iloc[j])
        
        print(f'For case {i+1}:{library.columns[j]},\tlocal similarity is {local_similarity[i,j]}')
    print('\n')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
    140             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 141         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    142 

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-281-05f4f1442b8c> in <module>
      2 for i in range(pCase_base.shape[0]):
      3     for j in range(pCase_base.shape[1]):
----> 4         local_similarity[i,j]=1-(abs(pCases.iloc[:,j]-pCase_base.iloc[i,j])/range_value.iloc[j])
      5 
      6         print(f'For case {i+1}:{library.columns[j]},\tlocal similarity is {local_similarity[i,j]}')

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Can pls help me to identify what is the problem?

Comment: Please show a sample of your data and enough of your code so that we can run it. As it is, it's very hard to decipher quite what's going on, and even harder to propose a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.